# Filter hits from aggregation buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter out hits to only return hits that are in my aggregation bucket.

```
{
"from": 0,
"aggs": {
    "id.raw": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "id.raw",
            "size": 0
        },
        "aggs": {
            "id_bucket_filter": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": {
                        "inline": "count == 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Result aggregation:

```
 "id.raw": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "1726200CFABY",
           "doc_count": 1
        }
     ]
  }
```

But I have 66 hits. I want only 1 hit. The 1 document for key 1726200CFABY

```
  "hits": {
  "total": 66,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
```

How can I get back only rows for the ids that match my aggregation buckets

EDIT: From Val comment I tried

```
 {
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "id.raw": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "id.raw",
            "size": 0
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                }
            },
            "id_bucket_filter": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": {
                        "inline": "count == 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I think i'm good now

Comment: You could use the `top_hits` aggregation as a sub-aggregation of your `terms` aggregation.